# Manager has noticed coworker's excessive breaks. Should I warn him?

Tags: professionalism, colleagues

A junior coworker of mine takes very long breaks every day.  I've timed them; he makes hour-long visits to the restroom every day.  He is paid by the hour, leaves after 8 hours, and is not allowed to work from home, so I know he's not making the time up.  He usually doesn't finish his work on time.

I've gone a long time not discussing this with him, but I'm now wondering if I should bring it up.  (If it were me, I'd want a coworker to warn me.)  He spends all this time in the restroom and there aren't enough stalls for this to not be a problem, so people are grumbling.  I overheard his manager complain he's never at his desk and somebody told him where he spends all that time, so it's been noticed.

I've casually mentioned to him before how he should try to limit his breaks, without saying more, but he didn't really pay attention to me.  Is it appropriate for me to be blunt and bring this up to him?  On one hand, it would be better if he heard it from me before he got chewed out from my manager.  But on the other hand, I really don't want to have this awkward conversation with him.  What is the professional thing to do in this circumstance?

---

UPDATE: Been a heck of a day and wanted to give you all an update. My manager pulled me in his office today and asked me if I knew of Hans' behavior of spending an hour in the bathroom at a time. I gave a non-committal answer, but said I had my suspicions. He then chewed me out for not bringing this to his attention earlier and not working with Hans on this issue.  (He emphasized that we were a team and I was supposed to have certain responsibilities as a senior member on the team).

A few hours later, Hans was called into my manager's office. After 45 minutes, he was escorted out of the building. My manager then sent out an e-mail saying that Hans was no longer a part of our team.

I'm still in a little bit of shock and am feeling a bit guilty over what happened.

Comment: This question is being discussed on meta: https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5974/36524

Comment: Is the employee a good worker otherwise? Or is the office better off without him altogether?

Comment: Rather than feeling guilty, take this as a learning experience.  If I may suggest an improvement, your update should be removed from the question and posted as an answer instead. That's solid advice from your manager: attempt to work with your coworker on the issue and if that fails, bring concerns to your manager.

Comment: The last thing you have to do is feeling guilty. It was his fault, not yours. He was perfectly aware of what he was doing and the risks he would face in case the manager noticed

Comment: Old I know, but based on your update your intuition was correct but you did not act upon them. It sounded like as a senior lead on the team, you should take notice of people's lack of work. In the future it doesn't hurt to bring up X is behind and you noticed a sudden behavioral change such as spending extreme time in the bathroom.

Answer (score 477):

> Hans will spend over an hour at a time going to the bathroom every day.

Perhaps your coworker has a medical condition. What business is that of yours?

> And if you're wondering, yes, I timed it.

Stop doing that, *right now*.

> Now I notice it every day when he's in the bathroom.

Try not to. Mind your own business, and focus on your own work.

> He also usually doesn't finish his work on time.

Unless you're his manager, this is — once again — none of your business.

> I'm now wondering if I should bring it up

No.

> I've casually mentioned to Hans before how he should try to limit his breaks (without mentioning I know how much time he spends in the bathroom), but he didn't really pay attention to me.

Of course he didn't. You're lucky he didn't report you for harassment. Don't do that again.

> Is it appropriate for me to be blunt and bring this up to him?

No.

> One on hand, it would be better if he heard it from me before he got chewed out from my manager.

No. *Only* his manager should be discussing things like this with him.

> But on the other hand, I really don't want to have this awkward conversation with him.

Good. Don't.

> What is the professional thing to do in this circumstance?

Stopping literally everything you're doing about it at the moment.

Get on with your work.

Comment: I feel like the medical condition thing only makes your answer less compelling. Are there actually medical conditions that (a) require spending an hour in the restroom on a regular basis, (b) would not be obvious/visible to others, and (c) that one would not expect an employer to have been already informed about? It's tough for me to imagine this all being true, so unless you have reason to believe this is a real possibility, I'd just remove that part of the answer.

Comment: "He also usually doesn't finish his work on time." ... "Unless you're his manager, this is — once again — none of your business." Not completely true. In small, self-managed teams (think Agile software), accountability to the team is important. However, it would likely be discussed in a periodic retrospective within the team before it became a problem with the manager.

Comment: @Mehrdad _"Are there actually medical conditions that (a) require spending an hour in the restroom on a regular basis, (b) would not be obvious/visible to others, and (c) that one would not expect an employer to have been already informed about?"_ Yes, there are. Also, a worker is not required to disclose all of their disabilities to their employer (because of medical privacy laws).

Comment: "What business is that of yours?" - why are people asking this question so accusingly? People often work as a team, if one of the links in your chain is missing for hours at a time, how does this NOT concern you and your team?

Comment: @ESR This topic was beaten to death in the comments, before a moderator deleted them all. Since they didn't even migrate them to chat, unfortunately you cannot follow it to read the answer to your question. Still, I don't see a great need to go into it again.

Comment: While your answer is, obviously, not without merit, the final result demonstrates that your answer is also less than ideal. The prescribed 'caring' results in a lack of care when carried to this extreme. Is he his brother's keeper? - To some extent, yes. Might he have been able to save the day? Maybe. Would the coworker have benefited from an approach less like the one you suggest? If you think the answer is no it would be very strange indeed. And? Is your comment on harassment sensible in a world where people care about others and not just their own skin? A: What world is that :-(.

Comment: In light of the question's update, I don't think this answer aged particularly well.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon If other people care about others, then there would be more of a care about people getting work done, and not how long they spend on the toilet. Also, in reference to some other comments made above: If one person (who is a _junior employee_) going to the toilet for 'too long' is enough to significantly disrupt your work then I really think you should work on your bus factor.

Comment: @FinnO'leary  It's obviously complex, and we probably do not disagree too much on the core issues. Given that the 'person of concern' was fired, presumably but not certainly as a consequence of the overall situation under discussion here, and [1] The managers comments about responsibilities, and the likelihood (not certainty) that (2a) Hans would rather have kept his job and  (2b) Hans would probably have adapted somewhat if he'd realised what was otherwise going to happen, then I find it hard to agree that the suggested hands off - back away - not my concern approaches were the best ones.

Comment: @Mehrdad I have a medical condition that causes me to breakout in a rash occasionally which takes about 30 mins to an hour to go away. I often just leave the building or go to the restroom for it to settledown rather than having people ask "why are you so red?" "Are you OK?". I think someone having a medical condition while maybe not likely, is definitely possible

Comment: As has been proved by the edit, this kind of mindset is wonderful for getting people fired. If you knew your coworker might get in trouble for some behavior, it's at least nice to tell them (so either they can correct said behavior or plan ahead for when the trouble lands), aside from any effects said behavior might have on your/your team's performance.

Comment: It apparently was not quite clear in the original post, but the OP is senior member of the team that Han was on, so it WAS his job to mentor co-worker, and he called out for not doing so and not raising it up. Sorry for the downvote, but I do not agree with your comments.  If it's a medical issue, then Han can bring it up with HR after his co-worker mentions it.

Comment: @MichaelW Why? According to described outcome, company EXPECTS, almost requires seniors to control juniors bathroom visits and have disgusting practice of "escorting out of building". Getting out of this shithole while you're still a junior is a good thing.

Comment: @Brad: In that case it's not really that you need to be in the bathroom but that you find it the easiest way to avoid people commenting on your looks. I feel for you and find it understandable, but it's not something I'd categorize as requiring the bathroom for an hour. Also, how do you manage not to tell your employer/supervisor why you're randomly away from your desk for an hour? If your boss needs you and you're gone... what do you say? And if it's a rare thing then recall that's also not what I asked about. (I'm also curious how much of a legal protection that would have too, if any...)

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov A company's business is their business. If your health issue is significant enough to affect your work output, it's the company's business. Maybe the need to accommodate, maybe not. But the status quo is not a working solution, as his firing proved. I would expect hour-long unscheduled breaks to raise eyebrows at any business.

Comment: -1: This question drives home the point that what the co-worker does and the consequences of those actions should be none of OP's business and that OP would be nosy at best and harassing at worst to do anything about it. This strategy would only work in a setting where every employee is accountable for themselves and no one else. This is simply not the case in a development setting where team members have to rely on each other to get work done - if one person isn't picking up the slack, it becomes everyone's business and therefore responsibility to address it.

Comment: @FinnO'leary: You're seriously telling me disability laws require employers to magically accommodate all employees who have disabilities. while being prohibited from even demanding that they *know* which employees are disabled and what accommodations they need? Citation needed, to say the least...

Comment: @MichaelW. - Yes, it's almost like OP didn't like the answer and has updated the question to try to make their actions like wise instead of foolhardy

Comment: Those suggesting this answer is 'wrong' because the employee in question was fired are endorsing very unpleasant business practices... Managers aren't supposed to be a secret police just waiting for an excuse to sack someone - if a member of staff appears to be slacking then the manager should speak to them and give them a warning (verbal or written, if appropriate). If the junior employee was stealing from the company or taking drugs in the office then fair enough, but long bathroom breaks are hardly grounds for immediate dismissal as described.

Comment: Not helping a junior employee out resulted in him getting fired and the senior getting a scolding. People should stop trying to dehumanize work areas. Teams exist, socialization and worrying about your co-workers should be empathized. "None of your business" is an awful, anti-social, counter productive behavior. If it's none of your business, the person will tell you.

Comment: @Erikus: The person, when first approached about this, completely ignored the OP. If that's not telling you that it's none of your business, what is?

Comment: @Mehrdad It's a really simple google search for you to do, so why you neglected to do that before claiming I was wrong is baffling. "Under the Americans with Disabilities Act, an employer may not ask a job applicant whether they have a disability (or about the nature of an obvious disability)" (https://www.workplacefairness.org/medical-privacy-workplace#3). Further searching confirms that doctors are unable to give out medical records without _written permission_ otherwise it's breaching doctor-patient confidentiality.

Comment: @FinnO'leary: There's a huge difference between demanding to know whether someone is disabled (really, nobody's business) and demanding to know whether they have any disabilities you need to accommodate (really, it's every part of their business). It makes zero sense to fault an employer for not accommodating a disability that they were explicitly kept in the dark about. Why you muddied the distinction is what I find baffling.

Comment: @Mehrdad _"It makes zero sense to fault an employer for not accommodating a disability that they were explicitly kept in the dark about."_ I agree, and I never stated that. My claim was that a worker is "not required to disclose all of their disabilities to their employer", which is a true statement. I don't recall faulting the employer, and never intended to muddy the distinction here, I simply (in retrospect) picked the wrong quote to prove that my statement was true. However, in retrospect, your characterization of my statement was a straw man.

Comment: @Mehrdad Getting back on topic, it may be that the employee in question was not previously impaired by the (presumed) disability in question, and was not noticing (or did not feel) that their work had been impaired to such a degree, and for that reason had not notified their employer of the functional impairment present (Which is all employers have a right to know).

Comment: @FinnO'leary: over here (Germany) there's a fairly clear distinction between two types of break (let's call them [short] break and [resting] pause): 5 min to the loo are a short break and they go on the employer. For longer (> 15 min) breaks employees are typically required to sign out (exception: pauses prescribed by law can be subtracted automatically from the signed in time. This is to make employees take their pause). 1 h is far inside "has to sign out" (and twice the legally required pause for an 8h working day). In case of a disability, the employee has 2 possibilities: either sign out..

Comment: ..and no need to disclose anything or bring a medical attestation saying they need this particular accomodation. (Which may be possible without disclosing the actual condition, btw.) My guess would be that in this case the accomodation would be to allow more long pauses, with employee still needing to deliver their full working hours - though maybe over a longer time frame each day (or a reduction in working hours and wage).

Comment: @DaveMongoose You're jumping to conclusions. Which is more likely, that he was fired on his first offense, or that he'd received prior warning not mentioned in this post? It was already KNOWN that he was not performing adequately, which would likely result in a talking to... And, depending on what OP said, it may have come across that OP had been the one to give the first warning (which Hans ignored). Not to mention it wasn't explicitly stated that he was let go for long bathroom breaks.

Comment: @MrE Thanks for your comment. I don't think that "this is stupid advice" is a very constructive way to describe an answer. Please consider rephrasing your comment into something a bit more useful and polite. Thanks!

Comment: I really think teams should be able to address things like this. If one person notices, others do, too. I am ambivalent about bringing it to the bosses attention, but person to person this should absolutely be addressed. And that's NOT harassment!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit OK, what I meant is if other people have noticed it then it probably is an issue. I'm assuming the person asking isn't going out of his way to rat on someone.

Answer (score 81):

Your manager is (I hope) trained on how to have these embarrassing conversations and how to suggest a change in behavior or accommodate a medical situation. You are not trained (imagine if he suddenly revealed medical details to you) and have no authority to offer accommodations or demand a change of ways. Leave the managing to the manager and cheer up your coworker afterwards if he is left upset by the conversation.

You've mentioned it once. Chances are others have too. At this point, the situation is not going to change due to coworker nudges.

Comment: *Your manager is (I hope) trained*... see the update to the question :(

Comment: While it's clear the manager didn't handle this well, that doesn't prove that the OP would have. Without the authority to say "stop doing that" or "oh ok I see why you're doing that, carry on" the OP can only say "hey if that's something you can stop you probably should because the boss is on to you" and I wouldn't have predicted that doing that would end up helpful.

Answer (score 64):

You have already warned him and it appears he has ignored you.

If you warn him again, then the manager talks to him - he may associate that as **your** fault and be annoyed at you.

I had a similar situation about a more serious issue and warned a colleague ... who did not listen, eventually management fired him...

You have been a friend and told him, stay out of it now.

Answer (score 37):

Maybe give him a friendly heads up that you overheard the manager talking about it, but keep the emphasis on friendly. Generally speaking, the bathroom habits of your colleagues are none of your business so put the emphasis on him being away from the desk without bringing up the toilet.

It's worth bearing in mind that there are medical conditions that require spending an above-average amount of time on the toilet, and the people who suffer from them generally don't want to talk about them.

Whatever you do, don't let him know that you've been timing his breaks. That'll just make you come over like a creepy stalker and you could find yourself being the one on the receiving end of a warning over it.

Comment: +1 for mentioning "creepy."

Comment: Indeed. Someone was on here a few weeks ago complaining about a total weirdo who kept track of bathroom breaks. Wondering whether there's a connection. I'm also wondering whether both posts are an elaborate troll of some kind...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit indeed, I wonder if they are in the same office.  To add to the answer, if that bathroom reason is any kind of disability, that is an area of law where one should *not* bungle around carelessly.

Comment: You might say that you should wash your hands of the matter and move on. :)

Comment: You might also question whether only one stall for "a fair sized office" complies with the relevant health and safety at work regulations. The fact that another one "is currently being built" doesn't change that situation. In the UK, the maximum number of employees in a workplace with only a  "single stall" is five - which doesn't sound like "a fair sized office" to me.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit *this question* I don't know about. It might be. But then again, I don't think this is really an impossible situation (either side of it). I recall that there was a similar story on the Ask A Manager site, where an employee had a medical reason to often visit the bathroom and a different peer was timing that. Besides, do you *really* believe humans are above this sort of pettiness? Especially at the workplace?

Comment: @VLAZ I wouldn't rule it out ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit to be fair, I wouldn't rule out a troll attempt, either. As I said, I don't know about this question - the style of it and coming so soon after the previous one makes me suspect it. Still, I don't think it's a highly unusual situation in the general case. If I've learned anything from reading stuff about workplaces (questions here, Ask A Manager, etc), is that people can be super petty about the weirdest things at work. Bathroom breaks, how many coffees a colleague drinks, what they eat, why somebody leaves on time. Or be offended at how they react after you harass them.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit last example was related to [this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/119646/offensive-language-behavior-from-co-worker-in-online-game/119672) - I ran out of characters to add the link. So, to surmise - I don't find "tracking bathroom breaks" to be in any way impossible. Sad as this may be.

Answer (score 29):

Yes, you should.  And I am angry with everyone else who answered or commented. Are we really to the point, again, where we avoid doing the morally right thing just because there might be personal risk?  Yeah, you might get into an HR stew and your co-worker might be angry that you are meddling.  Still, you should.   You said yourself that you'd want someone to do you the same favor, that is, at some personal risk, they would try to help you.

If your morals or ethics collapse the minute some inconvenience (or even just the possibility of inconvenience) arises, what sort of low-rent, dime-store morals were they?   The Allies put German soldiers in prison for not disobeying orders, even though to do so was certain death.   Now, by dint of nothing more than fear of a career set back, we think it's OK to not speak up when speaking up is needed?

This small tirade is not really for the OP, but for all the answerers who answered on the basis of self-service, as if that were the only criterion.

Comment: Indeed. It's sad that so few answers seem able to appreciate 'concern for others'. "None of your business" is fair comment at some point. But as the starting point when another's job is at stake (as proved to be the case) is overdoing it.

Comment: This is on the right track. But I would emphasize, there is absolutely 0 reason for HR to even be an issue. You don't have to talk about *why* they're gone, only warn them that the manager has *noticed* that they are away from their desk for long periods. A friendly heads up. There is no risk to yourself here. If you didn't know where they went you'd say the same thing - "hey, people noticed you're gone a lot and they're concerned". Solidarity with your fellow workers.

Comment: Completely agree. I am absolutely appalled by the most upvoted answer. Colleagues are supposed to give well-meaning constructive feedback to each-other, focusing on behaviour and not judgement. It depends on the company culture, of course, but if there is no healthy feedback culture in a team, then it's a not a good sign either way.

Answer (score 23):

First, this is potentially an issue with [ADA](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Americans_with_Disabilities_Act_of_1990), [Unruh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unruh_Civil_Rights_Act) or your jurisdiction's equivalent laws that protect persons with disabilities or medical conditions.  As such, anything remotely related to medical or disabilities  must be handled in compliance with relevant laws and with the utmost sensitivity.

What's more, there are things you may not know, that you should not know, or may not be allowed to know. If you had a horrible injury or disease that required you to spend an hour at noon doing some sort of awkward and very private medical procedure, *you really wouldn't want your privacy invaded by your coworkers*. So pause to realize that invading his privacy, *itself*, is a grave violence against him.

It is possible that the employee has already disclosed this to HR, and the issue is understood by them, and you didn't get the memo because you don't have any right.

On the other hand, maybe he's in there playing Candy Crush, but ADA is such a legal minefield that you must assume worst case.

So let's be clear on this point: the topic of **bathroom activity** is 110% totally out of bounds here. ***You cannot raise his absence issue in any way which could possibly relate to his use of the bathroom***.  Since you believe you know where he goes, do not ask him where he goes.  That can come to no good.

That said, two things are fair game.

First, you can state concern about his frequent absences, *assuming that you have no earthly idea where he goes*.  In fact, telling him "the boss was looking for you, and he's annoyed to not find you" is a decent "watching your bro's back" thing that I recommend.

Second, anyone who needs the facilities has every right to use all the standard/normal methods to deal with the **anonymous** individual hogging the stall.  Point being, no one has an inherent right to hog a stall as long as they pleases; *other people need to go to the bathroom too!* If the door is locked and there is no response from inside, then it's either a) an empty stall or b) a medical emergency; get a responsible person with a key.

If the person has a bona-fide need to have an hour in the bathroom, then that person needs to raise the requirement to management (they do not owe management the details, saying "it's a disability" invokes their ADA etc. protections)... Then management needs to communicate to employees that hourlong bathroom occupation is a necessity for certain anonymous  employees and that they have a right to privacy... Then you need to keep your schnozz out of it.  In that order.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90000/discussion-on-answer-by-harper-manager-has-noticed-coworkers-excessive-breaks).

Answer (score 18):

So with the results being announced and the #1 answer resulting in trouble for OP and our poor junior being given a hard life lesson, I think it's worth reviewing the results and efforts made and learn from our mistakes.

**Likely correct answer**
Matthew Barber's answer probably said it fairly well.
As the senior, OP was *expected* to have made an effort (hence being scolded for not doing so) and Matthew presented a manner in how to do it appropriately: *take the junior aside and mention that the manager is not happy with being away from the desk for an unknown reason.*

**Additional info that may have helped**
・Clearly stating if OP would like to protect the junior (or not). In other words, making the desired outcome clear.

**Community misses**
・If this was a disability issue, would the manager not have known beforehand? OP stated from the start that the manager has taken notice of junior's absence, but was unaware of being in the restroom. (Edited to "complain")
・OP's tone--OP is convinced that this is a junior with a poor work ethic goofing off. Junior is "immature," usually doesn't finish his work and is grumbled about by coworkers (who also know he's in the bathroom). Much more likely than a handicap is that junior is on his cell-phone (which, if known, should have been mentioned).
・Junior doesn't finish his work on time, which is likely directly correlated to the 1.5+ paid hours that OP is not actually working (if there was a disability, the workload should be adjusted). As such, depending on the work environment, that means work for others (not to mention the disruptions from "oh, he's not here..."). This means it likely IS coworkers business. The standard procedure is likely to go through management, which makes things official, however the OP's question was whether professional etiquette or duty requires OP to do things personally (or in this case, to prevent the managerial hell that was likely coming). Regardless of how people feel (overwhelmingly "not your problem!" it seems), the result has made it clear that OP is in a work culture where it IS their problem.
・Over-editing. Turned junior from a slacker who doesn't finish his work to a handicapped person who can't finish. I respect the value of editing to make questions more general and professional, it doesn't help OP if you edit away all of their context!

If you have more analysis to add, feel free!

Comment: *Mentioning that OP was in a role where it IS OP's responsibility to care for the performance of juniors* - It sounds to me like the OP didn't know that their manager expected them to do this. If they had already known that their manager wanted them to intervene in performance issues with junior team members then they wouldn't have had to ask this question. It sounds like the manager isn't actually doing a good job (not making OP's responsibilities clear, not saying something to the junior employee before it became necessary to fire them).

Comment: @BSMP Good point. Edited that out

Comment: In retrospect, it seems by the time OP posted here it was already the endgame, the firing was 99% likely to happen, and by the end there wasn't much OP could do to help.  It wasn't just the bathroom thing, the employee "usually doesn't finish his work on time".  While the boss may be unhappy about the bathroom issues, regular poor performance would probably be a much more serious concern. The bathroom thing just gave the boss an obvious justification for getting rid of him.

Comment: @krubo I agree for the most part, but I think if OP's conversation with the boss went along the lines of "Yes, I noticed. I spoke with him about that and his performance the other day and he's shown improvement since then," the outcome could have been completely different though

Comment: In fairness to OP though, OP did try at least once though! Hopefully this is a chance for junior to grow.

Comment: +1. Sometimes it seems like everyone here works for IBM in the 1950s, where everything is all official direct chain of command all the time. But everywhere I've worked, a more collaborative approach of senior employees guiding newer ones, working closely with the manager on team issues, and taking responsibility for overall team performance are common.

Answer (score 8):

This is ultimately a "nunya" situation; nunya funkin' business. Is this really how you wish to learn about a co-worker's private medical condition of which you have no right to know about?

If you have an issue with bathroom wait times then complain about bathroom wait times.

If you have an issue with working with someone who is never at their desk then complain that you can never find person xyz when you need them.

If this person is truly unaware that their hour-long bathroom breaks are causing an issue then they will be informed by the appropriate individual when the time comes. If they are already aware and they continue with the behavior then you should give them the benefit of the doubt and assume they need to do what they are doing.

Comment: *"they will be informed by the appropriate individual when the time comes"*, as nasty as it is, it is quite possible (even if not very likely) they will be fired without anybody actually ever telling them it was because of the long breaks.

Comment: @hyde Check out OP's update if you haven't already done so.

Answer (score 3):

It's really about how you bring it up.  What you do **not** want to do is to bring it up in a way that makes him think you are being judgmental.  This could cause a lot of problems for everyone involved (yourself included).  Things **not** to do include:

1) Mention any particular action he does or place he goes (e.g. "I notice you've been going to the bathroom for a long time")

2) Mention you have been stalking him (e.g. "I've been timing your breaks").  Also, just don't do that in general.  Since you have been doing it, you should both not tell him you have been doing it, and also stop doing it.

3) Give him any specific advice (e.g. "You should do/not do XYZ")

If you want to bring this up to him, to give him a heads up, things you **should** do include:

1) Make it short and sweet.  Do not have a discussion.  He does not get to respond with anything except a "yes, I understand".  If he starts to respond, cut him off and say "I just wanted to let you know, you don't have to justify yourself to me".

2) Mention that this has come to the attention of his boss, and that he might be under fire.  Make sure you are abundantly clear that it wasn't you who "told on" him.

3) Make sure you are discreet.  Don't talk in front of other coworkers, talk quietly, and make it quick.

My personal phrasing would be something like:

> Hey, Joe, I've been noticing you've been away from your desk for long periods of time.  I think Bill [Joe's boss] is starting to notice as well.  You might want to cut down on whatever it is you're doing, or you could get into some serious trouble.  Just giving you a heads-up.  It's not my business what you're doing, so you don't have to justify yourself to me, but I'm just giving you a heads up that Bill might start asking questions.

Answer (score 2):

I consider this to be at best a supplementary answer to [Lightness Races in Orbit's excellent straightforward answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/129372/33363) (I left essentially a three phrase version of this as a comment there, contexted as the difference between creepy and not), and as such it's intended to answer any lingering "but what if I just...?" (such as: "but what if I just want to warn my coworker about their boss noticing them doing this").

### What *can* you say?

What your colleague does (particularly on break, in private) is precisely... none of your business, as many others have repeated. How long they are not at their desk is also not your business. Why they are not at their desk is not your business.

What **is** your business, and what you can bring up with your coworker, is interaction you have had or *directly* observed going on (and when I say directly, I mean actually what you saw or heard, **not** what conclusions you then assumed about it).

If their boss comes and asks where they are, you can relay that to your coworker. "So-and-so was asking for you, I didn't know where you were so that's what I told them". Don't speculate about where they were. Don't speculate to anyone else about where they were. Don't **speculate** about **anything**. For example "So-and-so was looking for you, *I bet they're annoyed at your 1 hour bathroom breaks*" is **you purely assuming and speculating** on the latter half. Don't do that.

Being a friend at work or at least a good coworker starts and ends with not **pushing** in uninvited on personal issues (not to be mistaken with offering support in a way that doesn't push), which is absolutely what's going on when it's a peer (or under a lateral reporting structure) and not *your* report. Whatever your coworker's 1 hour bathroom(?) breaks involve is between your coworker and their boss and HR. You have no knowledge of whatever arrangements they have made, and such arrangements would not be any of your business if they existed.

If something about your coworker's performance is affecting *your* work, then that is up to you to address with your boss, but I would caution to keep it to the direct facts of what is having an effect, NOT your assumptions about what is behind that.

"Coworker isn't keeping up with deadlines" is a direct fact. *That's* what *you* need your manager to deal with for you.

"Coworker isn't keeping up with deadlines because of 1 hour bathroom breaks" is **your** speculative assumption, and as someone not managing that person, not your call to make, and WHY your coworker isn't keeping up or is causing bottle necks for you is something for your manager to figure out and figure out how to resolve, not you.

Whatever you can do to let go of this interest of yours in your coworker's related time is in your best interest. You're not their boss. So if their boss has taken an interest, yes, you can communicate that *actually observed* interaction (not your subsequent assumptions/speculation) on the part of their boss. If it's affecting you directly due to workflow, you can in turn address that. But don't turn this into you trying to clock watch someone else at work who isn't your report, and seriously don't turn this into speculating about why they're gone for so long.

### We're all human and curious

...but this is the type of road that, professionally, you're better off turning away from. This is one of those cases that for everyone involved, about the best thing you can do is to keep things professional about this, in context with what your role actually is (e.g. not being their manager). I realize that there's also a strong "fairness" sense that can impact here, which is also one of those very human things (fairness is one of the earlier psychological social constructs to develop, showing up even fairly early in babies) but ultimately you need to find a route to letting go of your concern over that however you possibly can, because you simply don't know everything going on, it's not your place to know, and it's not your place to handle it. Quite simply whatever's going on may even be quite "fair" in context and regards to you, if for example it involves a medical issue on the part of your colleague... but ultimately, regardless, *you* have to figure out how to resolve *your* feelings about the situation and whatever is driving you to take such a deep interest, so that your own feelings on this can quit impacting *you* (which they clearly are, even if only to the extent that you're now clock watching a coworker).

### What if you're simply genuinely concerned about your coworker?

Then keep *that* conversation focused on offering support, without prying. But don't mix it with "hey I think the boss is on to you".

"I just want you to know, if you ever need anything that I can help with, I'm here for you" is one way to word that which doesn't involve essentially saying "hey I've been stalking your bathroom breaks".

It's also low pressure, because you're not assigning anything that then needs a refutation or asks for some kind of direct answer, such as "Is everything ok?". It's pretty easy to answer "Thanks" to that if they want to drop the conversation. If *they* don't continue the conversation, **drop the conversation**. The point was to being *actually* supportive, not prying. And this is supposed to be about *them*, not *you*: yes, letting go of your interest is hard, but if you actually care, that's what you need to do.

If they then ask "why are you asking", that's an appropriate time to mention, simply, that you've gradually noticed that they seem to be away a fair bit (or, as a better point of focus, that you've noticed that they seem to be struggling to meet deadlines), even though it's not as if you're keeping track, and you don't know why and it's none of your business, but you do care about them as a colleague so you wanted to express your support if there's anything going on they might need help with.

Answer (score 2):

I've been in several workplaces where people have been eager to earn 'brown-nose-points' at the expense of others. It is a nasty thing and now I tend to build files on everybody so I can fight back in case people try it against me. I feel it's a waste of time but I also feel I need to protect myself.

In my opinion the regular people in teams (non-managers) should stick together and cover as much as possible for each other, especially when it comes to things like 'private time', bathroom breaks etc.

I'm not saying that we should lie - but there's absolutely no need to report things, nor to confirm 'suspicions' from management.

Now, such extensive bathroom breaks are over the top unless there's a valid medical condition. But we should deal with in within the team and not involve management.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to provide another answer despite there being already several of them, because they all missed a crucial point. I had not before because I was afraid I could not articulate it properly. However, having just watched this video, I remembered this question, and came back to write this answer, as I find this video to be good prompt, and a perfect description of what most likely happened. Please watch this, especially towards the end, where the Prof describes toilet breaks: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qYvXk_bqlBk

Of course I'm speculating, but there's a more than reasonable chance, and many clues hinting that this was very likely the case:

- Your colleague is (was) an introvert. The typical kind, quiet, doesn't go out for beers, terrified of confrontation, doesn't interact much, prefers to be lost in their work without distractions, etc.
- You, your boss, and the environment in general sounds like a fairly extroverted environment (of the "go-getter", "if-it's-broken-fix-it-yesterday", "act-like-a-pack", "", "Hey-I'm-just-here-to-make-sure-you're-working", "I'll-time-your-toilet-breaks" kind).
- Also, you didn't specify what the actual profession is, but I got the vibe that it is the kind of business environment typically associated with rigidity and strictness of rules and hierarchy, where creativity and flexibility are not typically expected, let alone encouraged.
- As an introvert in an environment of extroverts, he would have found the very environment stressful and overloading. Compounding that, presumably, he would have also been perceived as not being a 'team player' in the manner usually perceived by extroverts, and the toilet breaks presumably seen as avoidance behaviour and lack of commitment to the workplace.
- The highly extroverted environment caused high levels of anxiety and tension to this worker, who needed to 'defuse' and reset in the quiet environment of a toilet, at relatively frequent and lengthy intervals. Furthermore, flagging the 'toilet situation' as a 'situation' signalling avoidance and lack of commitment would in itself compound the anxiety and overloading, leading to a vicious and anxious cycle of unavoidably needing more and more of it over time.
- Note that this is *extremely common*, especially in males:

  - https://www.reddit.com/r/AskMen/comments/36sncy/men_of_askreddit_do_you_ever_just_sit_on_the/
  - ["You ever been so miserable at work, you just spend extra time sitting on the toilet"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bkvAKfCNnUw&feature=youtu.be&t=2m44s) (Chris Rock, excerpt from stand-up comedy)
- There are no objective measures or formal incentives employed in your workplace by which to gauge a worker's productivity and value added, and therefore, particularly in an extroverted culture, the metric used to gauge this defaults to otherwise irrelevant heuristics of a psychological nature, like "loudness of work", and "hours not in toilet".
- We note that there was no mention of this worker not actually being good at their job in terms of value added, or of the toilet breaks actually objectively impeding amount and quality of work produced. This in itself leads us to conclude that his amount and quality of work (anxiety notwithstanding) were at the very least not unreasonable or sub-par (otherwise it's the elephant in the room and it would have been mentioned as extremely relevant; and the OP hints at a feeling of guilt, which would be far less likely if the worker was 'deserving' of being let go for far more than just toilet breaks).
- Since there's no overt *"medical"* issue for an introvert to justify needing to recompose oneself in this manner before going back into the extroverted jungle, when the boss asked directly, and, as prompted by others, effectively perceived and framed the problem as "why do you steal company time", there was no good believable answer that could satisfy him; and you can just imagine an introvert wanting to please by sheepishly apologising for everything instead of attempting to flip the tables or go in the offense to gain control of the situation. Which in turn reinforces the perception of the introvert worker as a weakling unambitious underperforming beta extra-weight who has no place in our team of alpha go-getter stars, and therefore needs to be let go.

Obviously, I could be way off the mark here. I am speculating based on subtle clues, and more than happy to be wrong. If this is the case, disregard, sorry to come across as an ass.

But, if any of the above rings any bells, then sorry to add to your feelings of guilt, but yes, it sounds very likely you got someone fired for effectively being an introvert, despite being good at their job, regarding an issue where they needed support instead. And, unfortunately (and if it is any consolation), I have seen variants of this scenario happen many times. Therefore my main motivation for writing this answer is not to vilify you or weigh your conscience, but in the hope that some other poor shmuck in your situation reads this and at least considers this interpretation.

Having said that, it also sounds like you did him a favour, so I wouldn't lose too much sleep over it. A person who's so tense, unhappy and undervalued at work, that they need frequent toilet breaks just to defuse, is likely going to be much happier in a different, more creative, less "let's-sell-stuff-every-second-counts-go-go-go" kind of environment anyway.